# How can use current day as column name in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server.

All days exist as columns in the table (Monday, Tuesday, ...).

The data types of the columns are bit.

In this case, how can I check current day is true in `where` condition?

Like this

```sql
select *
from Servis
where [FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dddd')] = 1 --Current day
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw, fix your design. Have one row per day, not one column per day. Otherwise you have to use Dynamic SQL, and honestly, this is going to make using your table very difficult.

Comment: Generally a bad idea - you've effectively put some of your data into the table's *metadata*, and now is the *start* of your struggles as you try to combine data and metadata querying at the same time.

Comment: This is business application. I cant edit design :(( . I'm trying to find a solution in an existing structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM Servis
> WHERE CASE DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) 
>       WHEN 'Monday' THEN Monday
>       WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN Tuesday
>       WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN Wednesday
>       WHEN 'Thursday' THEN Thursday
>       WHEN 'Friday' THEN Friday
>       WHEN 'Saturday' THEN Saturday
>       WHEN 'Sunday' THEN Sunday
>       END = 1;
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6816f2d63efc25f78574b955beab5707)*

Answer (score 0):

As Larnu mentioned the design should be changed in order to ease of query. But when you insist to keep this structure; here is the sample:

```
-- Assuming This is the structure of table
Create Table Servis (
    Saturday bit Default (0), 
    Sunday bit Default (0), 
    Monday bit Default (0), 
    Tuesday bit Default (0), 
    Wednesday bit Default (0), 
    Thursday bit Default (0), 
    Friday bit Default (0)
)
GO

INSERT Servis DEFAULT VALUES
GO

Declare @ColumnName sysname= FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dddd')

DECLARE @Result INT
DECLARE @Params nVARCHAR(4000) = N'@Result INT OUTPUT'
Declare @Query nVarchar(4000) = REPLACE(N'Set @Result = (SELECT @ColumnName FROM Servis)', N'@ColumnName', @ColumnName)

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @Query, @params = @Params, @Result = @Result OUTPUT

PRINT @Result
```

Comment: This working but i'm cant use `exec` for where condition.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to save the result? If yes I will update answer to save result in variable. @YahyaAltintop

Comment: @YahyaAltintop See updated answer.

Comment: It's working there is no problem. But it's not required to use exec for this simple problem.